# Automatic login for twitter and google if user is looged on respective sites

Tags: php, twitter-oauth, google-openid

I was implementing open id login system for facebook, google and twitter. 
 Facebook automatic login is working perfectly fine but not able to implement same for google or twitter.

Please let me know if some open source script is there, from where I can take some help.
Let me know if you want me to post my code.

Answer (score 0):

As for twitter, the most easy option would be using the @Anywhere library, it includes a login button which works similar to the facebook login button:
http://dev.twitter.com/anywhere/begin#login-signup

Google, unfortunately, doesnt have a simple login with google button, so you will have to use their OpenID implementation:
http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html

The easiest way to do so would be by using the following PHP class: 
http://andrewpeace.com/php-google-login-class.html

If this seems to complicated, you could also use the following service, which implements login buttons for Google, Facebook, Twitter and more:
https://rpxnow.com/